# What's the meaning of "contribution" and "contribute" in computer English?

Tags: meaning

The following sentence is all about [Eclipse RCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Rich_Client_Platform):

> You may also be asking yourself why we have not used any of the Workbench’s
>   extension points for defining actions. After all, Eclipse is all about declarative contributions.
>
> This is a common question—when should an RCP application use the
>   declarative Workbench extension points as opposed to simply creating the actions
>   programmatically as in Hyperbola? In the context of a single small application,
>   there is usually no need to use the extension point approach. In fact, an RCP application
>   must minimally define a top-level menu structure using programmatic
>   actions because without this, there would be no place to contribute actions
>   declaratively.

What is the meaning of "contribution" and "contribute" in these sentences?

Comment: It might be better to ask this question on StackOverflow. This does not appear to be the normal English meaning of "contribution".

Comment: I asked the question on StackOverflow ,but StackOverflow let me ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the real meaning now. ***contribution and contribute*** are just like what user *Noah* told me.What is **contribution and contribute** in Eclipse RPC?

There is a shared mechanism between different RCP plug-ins: 
If a plug-in wants to share its **actions** ,**perspectives**, and so on with other plugins, it has to declare them in a "plugin.xml" file.

And the beings what the plugin declares in the plugin.xml file can be requested by other plugins or itself.

So the beings are called "contribution"(contributed to other plugins), and declaring them for other plugins called "contribute".  The contributions are expressed in the form of "extension" element in the plugin.xml file.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers your question. I think you are saying that *contribution* and *contribute* refer to plugins and more specifically to methods or something related, but I am not sure. Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: hey KitFox.I have edited my answer,you try to take a look again

Answer (score 0):

*Contribution* is a noun and *contribute* is a verb. You contribute something by performing the action of contribution.

Comment: hi, Noah. I still cann't have a good idea

Comment: @JZ.Hunt What's it that you don't understand about the two? If you want to give some money to a welfare, you *contribute* money to that organization. The money itself is a *contribution.* The action of giving them money is *contribute.*